# Tag request - [gerbil]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm a little off the point where I can create tags here, so I thought I'd see if anyone here would create the tag [gerbil](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerbil), as animal-specific tags seem to be welcome(?), unless it's not likely it'd be used enough.

I'm asking specifically after wondering what I should have tagged [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/how-do-i-get-my-gerbils-to-enjoy-being-held/7000#7000).

Comment: Done and swapped it out on your question for the rodent tag.